# Test debounce with mocha-chai-sinon

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, chai, debouncing

I want to test my `debounce` function but the same applies to underscore or lodash.

I want to use mocha, chai's `assert` and possibly sinon.

I prepared a [codepen](https://codepen.io/centurianii/pen/BMGOOG).

Sinon's timers give me a headache; when I ask my debounce to run first I still get a response that debounced callback hasn't been called whereas it was!

Let's see the code:

```
// sinon timers
it('should not run debounced function too early', function() { 
  var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  var delay = 100;
  var targetFn = sinon.spy();
  var delayedFn = g3.debounce(targetFn, {delay: delay, fireStart: false, fireLast: true});
  // for lodash:
  //var delayedFn = _.debounce(targetFn, delay, {leading:false, trailing:true});
  delayedFn();
  clock.tick(delay - 1);
  clock.restore(); 
  sinon.assert.notCalled(targetFn); 
});
```

Erroneous results we take from underscore when we change the values that control run first/last. Can someone propose an alternative? a correction?

I also found [this](https://gist.github.com/stephennancekivell/5899425) link for tests probably in Jasmine.

I want to modify the next block to mocha:

```
it('should only happen once', function(){
    var count = 0;
    runs(function(){
        var fn = underscore.debounce(function(){
            count += 1;
        }, 100);

        fn();
        fn();
        fn();
    });

    waitsFor(function(){
        return count > 0;
    }, 'didnt execute', 200);

    runs(function(){
        expect(count).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Is this possible?

I can only see this mocha test to success:

```
  it('shouldnt execute immediately', function(){
    var hasHappened = false;

    var fn = g3.debounce(function(){
        hasHappened = true;
    }, {fireFirst: false, fireLast: true, delay: 100});

    chai.assert(hasHappened === false, 'error: callback has called');
    fn();
    chai.assert(hasHappened === false, 'error: callback has called');
  });
```

If you know a bunch of test cases out there it would be nice so I can see my errors.

Comment: I just ran your first test using `sinon` with `lodash` and setting `leading` to `true` and `targetFn` was called as expected.

Comment: It seems my Date object is not working with sinon timers!??

Comment: ...also notice that other libraries do NOT use Date objects but setTimeout() etc.. going one step further this means that ALL code that uses Date objects will fail??? (console.log(Date.now() == 0 when sinon timers are used)

Comment: for the moment I treat it as testing platform error and not error of code under test

Comment: ...just managed to overcome sinon timers issue: `clock.tick(1000)` BEFORE calling `debounce()` THEN calling `debounce()` LASTLY `clock.tick(1000 + delay - 1)` @~:(!

Comment: ...LASTLY `clock.tick(delay - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally [found](https://codepen.io/centurianii/pen/BMGOOG) a solution for sinon's buggy timers as internally they override the `Date` object, `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` etc.

The question here is if we are wiling to change our code for the shake of a test or even worse integrate testing conditions inside our code.

The solution is to initiate a timer with...a time!

```
/*** file 'g3.debounceTest.js' ***/
describe('g3.debounce', function() {
  it('should not run debounced function with: 1 call at elapsed < delay & fireLast: true', function() { 
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    // sinon remedy avoids buggy behavior
    clock.tick(1000);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    var delay = 100;
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var targetFn = function(){console.log('eventually debounced was called!'); spy()};
    var delayedFn = g3.debounce(targetFn, {delay: delay, fireFirst: false, fireLast: true});
    // for lodash:
    //var delayedFn = _.debounce(targetFn, delay, {leading: false, trailing: true});
    delayedFn();
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    clock.restore(); 
    sinon.assert.notCalled(spy); 
  });

  it('should run debounced function once with: 1 call at elapsed < delay & fireFirst: true', function() { 
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    // sinon remedy avoids buggy behavior
    clock.tick(1000);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    var delay = 100;
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var targetFn = function(){console.log('eventually debounced was called!'); spy()};
    var delayedFn = g3.debounce(targetFn, {delay: delay, fireFirst: true, fireLast: false});
    // for lodash:
    //var delayedFn = _.debounce(targetFn, delay, {leading: true, trailing: false});
    delayedFn();
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    clock.restore(); 
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy); 
  });

  it('should run debounced function once with: 3 calls at elapsed < delay & fireFirst: true', function() { 
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    // sinon remedy avoids buggy behavior
    clock.tick(1000);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    var delay = 100;
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var targetFn = function(){console.log('eventually debounced was called!'); spy()};
    var delayedFn = g3.debounce(targetFn, {delay: delay, fireFirst: true, fireLast: false});
    // for lodash:
    //var delayedFn = _.debounce(targetFn, delay, {leading: true, trailing: false});
    /* 1 */delayedFn();
    /* after 99ms */
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    /* 2 */delayedFn();
     /* after 99ms */
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    /* 3 */delayedFn();
    clock.restore(); 
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy); 
  });

  it('should run debounced function once with: 3 calls at elapsed < delay & fireLast: true', function() { 
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    // sinon remedy avoids buggy behavior
    clock.tick(1000);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    var delay = 100;
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var targetFn = function(){console.log('eventually debounced was called!'); spy()};
    var delayedFn = g3.debounce(targetFn, {delay: delay, fireFirst: false, fireLast: true});
    // for lodash:
    //var delayedFn = _.debounce(targetFn, delay, {leading: true, trailing: false});
    /* 1 */delayedFn();
    /* after 99ms */
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    /* 2 */delayedFn();
     /* after 99ms */
    clock.tick(delay - 1);
    //console.log(Date.now());
    /* 3 */delayedFn();
    /* after 100ms */
    clock.tick(delay);
    clock.restore();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  });
});
/***end file 'g3.debounceTest.js' ***/
```

I also injected a `spy()` inside a callback as I wanted to see what happens with that callback and I noticed by surprise that the callback runs after we call `clock.restore();` but `sinon` does not have a way to audit this and remains completely ignorant of what happens after `clock.restore();`.

That's the reason why I forced to write `clock.tick(delay);` at the last case in order to allow `sinon` to "see" last invocation happens.

Lastly if you come with more ideas testing such an asynchronous code I'd love to see them.